# Как в RadioGroup на Android Studio реализовать выбор одного RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Использую ScrollView, в котором лежит RadioGroup. Вставил в RadioGroup несколько RadioButton, запустил на проверку, а RadioButton можно одновременно все выделить. Все элементы добавляю динамически, не через форму. Нашел только, что в ListView можно использовать метод setChoiceMode, но он только у ListView. Как сделать нечто похожее в ScrollView или RadioGroup не знаю.
rb - RadioButton, rg- RadioGroup

```
for(int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
    rb = new RadioButton(context);
    rb.setText(answer[i]);
    rg.addView(rb);
}
```

Comment: Показывайте код как добавляете кнопки в `RadioGroup`

Comment: Добавил. Почему-то именно при добавлении не через форму RadioButton неправильно работают, через форму все отлично получается

Comment: Попробуйте добавить id к RadioButton `rb.setId(i);` перед добавлением в группу.

Comment: Блин! Ну наконец-то! Спасибо большое, все заработало! Не подскажите, почему так? И, пожалуйста, добавьте ответ к этому вопросу, чтоб его видно было, а то в комментариях не сразу могут заметить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `RadioButton` нужно указать `id`. По нему `RadioGroup` определяет, какой элемент выбран и отключает остальные.

Соответственно `id` должен быть уникальным внутри одной группы. Для этого можно использовать индекс цикла:

```
for(int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
    rb = new RadioButton(context);
    rb.setText(answer[i]);
    rb.setId(i);
    rg.addView(rb);
}
```